# Are there any negative effects to using base class pointers on derived classes in c++?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

I generally avoid using class pointers , since references seem way more efficient. But I have been recently forced to use them as they present the only (efficient and easy) solution to binding functions with window ids in my windows api wrapper. I have created an array of class WinControl. in my WinHandler class which handles the WndProc (Window Procedure) and add all the widgets used in the program to that array.

```
class WinControl   //These are not the entire classes, just the significant parts.
{
    public:
        int WinID;
        virtual void Click(void) = 0; //Pure Virtual Function.
}

class WinHandler
{ 
    WinHandler() : WCount(0) { }
    WinControl* WidgetSet[MAX_LENGTH];   // Or I can use an STL vector...
    int WCount;
    void AddWidget(Widget* w) { WCount++; WidgetSet[WCount] = w; }
}
```

Then then I use:

```
if (WidgetSet[i]->ID == LOWORD(wParam)) WidgetSet[i]->Click();
```

Will this approach be alright in the long run? As the Objects actually stored in the WidgetSet will all be derivatives of class WinControl. Can anyone suggest a better approach?

NOTE: I have tried to make my question as clear as possible. If u still can't get what I am asking, please comment and I will try to elaborate the question.

Comment: Picking between pointers and references should not be matter of efficiency, but a matter of semantics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are storing in the widget set is a pointer. NOT the object. The problem with your design is that it is not clear who is supposed to own the object thus destroy it.

I would change the interface to make ownership explicit.

### Option 1:

WinHandler does **NOT** own the widget:

```
void AddWidget(Widget& w) { WCount++; WidgetSet[WCount] = &w; }
```

### Option 2:

WinHandler **Takes** ownership of the widget

```
void AddWidget(std::auto_ptr<Widget> w) { WCount++; WidgetSet[WCount].reset(w); }
std::auto_ptr<WinControl> WidgetSet[MAX_LENGTH];
```

### Option 2a:

(for those with newer compilers)
WinHandler **Takes** ownership of the widget

```
void AddWidget(std::unique_ptr<Widget>& w) { WCount++; WidgetSet[WCount] = std::move(w); }
std::unique_ptr<Widget> WidgetSet[MAX_LENGTH];
```

### Option 3:

(for those with newer compilers)
WinHandler **shares** ownership of the widget

```
void AddWidget(const std::shared_ptr<Widget>& w) { WCount++; WidgetSet[WCount] = w; }
std::shared_ptr<Widget> WidgetSet[MAX_LENGTH];
```

Comment: The usual caveat that `auto_ptr` cannot be used in STL containers.

Comment: with a compiler that supports it, try shared_ptr. Or unique_ptr but you'll have to std::move it in and out of the container.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is OK, but watch out for memory leak: don't forget to **delete** everything :)

Comment: The solution is not OK. This is a solution that would be written by a "C with classes" programmer. The interface does not specify any ownership semantics on a pointer being passed. This is more like C code than C++ code.

Comment: @Martin Sorry about that, you see I am (or was) actually a C Programmer, and only switched to C++ to use OOP in my code, so I am (or was) exactly what u said , a "C with classes" programmer. But after reading ur answer I understand how important STL and other C++ specific features are, and hope to use them in future projects (and this one). Thanks.

Comment: @Martin: I just answered the question as it is formulated. There are no `negative effects` as such upon using pointers with polymorphism. `C vs C++` is an important, but *different* matter.